# Move Two Lines to make the equation correct

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking

Move 2 lines (one short and the other long) from one side (either) to the other side of the = sign to make the equation correct. Cannot use "not equal to" sign. You must move 2 lines as stated. Some creative thinking may be needed.

[image: some lines depicting 410=9/5]

Hint:

> Think of letters

Comment: Are all lines supposed to be the same length?

Comment: No. The lines are of the length as given in the image. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Starting point

> The [Bekenstein-Hawking formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics) for the entropy of a black hole, $S$, in [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units), is given by $$ S = A/4$$ where $A$ is the area of the event horizon.
>  We may rewrite this equation as $$4 = A/S$$ or perhaps $$4-0 = A/S$$

Given that, we move the following (highlighted) lines

> [image]

To the opposite sides of the equals sign to give

> [image]

Comment: "Move 2 lines (one short and the other long) from one side", but you moved from left and right side. is it okay like that?

Comment: @Oray My interpretation is that each line must move from one side to the other (but not necessarily originating from the same side). Although the phrasing in the question is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score -2):

> 4 - 0 = 9 - 5
>  That is, the  1 becomes a minus and the division also becomes a minus.

Comment: It says to move two lines from one side of the equality sign to the other.

Comment: The way I see it, the division sign should become the minus on the left side, and the 1 should become the subtraction side on the other one.